# How to write custom database adapter for django using JDBC drivers?

Tags: django, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a web-app in Django and backend in Hbase. To access hbase I'm using Apache Phoenix to query hbase.
Phoenix has jdbc drivers exposed.

How can I integrate Phoenix with Django ORM using these jdbc drivers?
Can I write customer db adapter or is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use Django, then you should use a python database driver, not a JDBC driver.

Comment: You are right. But Apache Phoenix has only exposed JDBC client/drivers for its access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also been trying to see if it is possible to extend the ORM of django to use apache phoenix. but for a start, you can checkout

JayDeBeAPI

or

[phoenixdb](https://oxygene.sk/2015/07/phoenix-database-adapter-for-python/)

As an example, I was able to connect and retrieve data using the phoenixdb package.

1. Install the package via pip install phoenixdb
2. Run the sample code:

   import phoenixdb

   database_url = 'http://localhost:8765/?v=1.6'

   conn = phoenixdb.connect(database_url, autocommit=True)

   cursor = conn.cursor()

   cursor.execute('select * from WEB_STAT limit 1')

   rs = cursor.fetchall()

   print rs

It is important to know the version of the phoenix you are using, you can find the details in the link provided.