# Using Apache Ignite with Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, orm, ignite

We have an existing Apache Ignite in-memory DB with lots of stored data. I want to connect my existing Django web application to the Ignite DB in order to query the existing data. Are there any examples of how to connect a Django application to an Apache Ignite DB and how to query the DB using the Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JDBC drivers with Django ORM: [How to write custom database adapter for django using JDBC drivers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37708696/how-to-write-custom-database-adapter-for-django-using-jdbc-drivers)

Then, you can use Ignite JDBC driver: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/JDBC/jdbc-driver

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM requires a special adapter for each kind of database server. Such an adapter is called “database backend” in Django terminology. There is no Django database backend for Ignite. There is also no universal, middle-ground backend I know of, that can be used with Ignite.

You can implement your own custom backend ([guidelines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#subclassing-the-built-in-database-backends)) or try to pick up the latest attempt in creating a more-or-less server-independent [ODBC backend](https://github.com/lionheart/django-pyodbc). But in your place I'd probably not get involved in any of this, since it implies a lot of work not directly related to your task.

I'd just convert the data with one-off script (or Django management command), using [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) or [pyignite](https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/modules/platforms/python) as a source and Django model as a target.